# UML Class Diagram feedback on current state

Tags: uml, class-diagram

So. I'm trying to create a UML class diagram of a monitoring system for an assignment. My current currently addresses the monitoring system with the alarms followed with the system. My problem however is that i'm not quite sure that my alarm system is going to work at all.

So, how this system works is that the monitoring system gathers information on the vital signs for Heart rate (determined from ECG class) BloodPressure and temperature.The Blood pressure monitor has 2 ways of getting the blood pressure.

With the alarms, they only activate when the monitors exceed a certain limit.

My question is this method accomplishing the goals of the system? I'm really sceptical right though of the vital sign classes
My idea was that the vital signs will be gathered into the monitor vitals class
but each vital sign has its own set time interval where it's meant to be updated and then displayed
I feel like my model here doesn't do that.
Another problem I feel is that the alarm structure is incorrect since the vital signs are intended to be sent to the alarms every time they are updated
[image]

Comment: Hey, what's your question?

Comment: @muszeo I've changed the thread but i'm asking if this is the correct methodology or if i'm mistaken with my approach, apologies

Comment: In your previous question you've been already told, that this page is not intended for questions "hey, is my diagram correct". Look for a forum for UML, BAs or of the sort and please post it there. This time I'm joining to VTC.

Comment: If you were more specific in your questions (so rather than asking if your methodology is right, focus on your specific problem), your question might be on-topic. But you definitely have to rephrase your question.